# Ubound(array) function clearing array

Tags: arrays, vba

I'm fairly new at VBA, but this error just doesn't make sense to me.  I'm trying to find the ubber bound of an array, but when I run the uBound(array) function it clears the array and then returns an error; I can't figure out why.  I stopped the code on "Let ub = UBound(Unique,1)" and iterated through it, and it actually had the values in the array in step 1, step 2 cleared the array, step 3 called an error.  This is also the location that the error first occurs.

Thanks for the help all:

```
Sub count_values(unique() As Variant, cccyarray() As Variant)

Dim m As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim ub As Variant
Dim ub2 As Variant

Let ub = UBound(unique, 1)
Let ub2 = UBound(unique)
```

Comment: Why using "Let", it will set properity for the array.  Do you mean "Set"?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problem you're having, using Excel 2010.  What are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this notation before, but I usually use UBound in a different way. For example if Unique().length is 5 and Last entry in the array is "Orange" then :

```
UBound(Unique) 'Returns 5
```

And

```
Unique(UBound(Unique)) 'Returns Orange
```

Based on this, I would suggest if you would like to store the first entry of Unique() into ub

```
ub = Unique(1)
```

and if the last entry of the array into ub2

```
ub2 = Unique(UBound(Unique))
```

Comment: `UBound(unique, 1)` is a statement that returns the *upper bound* of the array's *first* dimension, not a method of returning the array's first element.